# create sub Array on join instead of new entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 4 lectures where each lecture has it's own name:

**jbc2014_lezingen**

[image: the lectures]

Then for each lecture there will be questions, in this case 2 for each lecture:

**jbc2014_vragen**

[image: the questions for the lectures]

I use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jbc2014_lezingen
INNER JOIN jbc2014_vragen 
ON jbc2014_lezingen.id=jbc2014_vragen.lezing_id";
```

This results in something like:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [lezing_naam] => lezing 1
            [lezing_id] => 1
            [vraag] => foobar?
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [lezing_naam] => lezing 1
            [lezing_id] => 1
            [vraag] => foobar?
        )
       etc.
```

So the array size is based on the amount of the questions, not the amount of the lectures.
I would like something like:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [lezing_naam] => lezing 1
                [lezing_id] => 1
                [questions] Array (
                    [0] => [vraag] => foobar?
                    [1] => [vraag] => foobar?
                ) 


            )
```

Where the questions are in an array (vraag means question).
How can this be done?

Later on I need the multiple choice answers in an array inside the questions as well. But I think that won't be hard after having this one fixed.

Comment: This would be very difficult to do if you expect it just as sql.  In theory if you knew that each lecture had two and only two questions you can join two of the exact same query you did on A_vragen.lezing_id <> B_vragen.lezing_id and A_jbc2014_lezingen.id=B_jbc2014_vragen.lezing_id.  But its just easier to parse it out serverside with some kind of loop and a hash structure.

Comment: Yes, you can't do that with pure SQL. Do you need a working solution now or you need to spend time looking for solution that is not worth time you spend on it?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you could do is something like this -

```
SELECT jbc2014_lezingen.id as lezing_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(vraag) as vraags 
FROM jbc2014_lezingen
INNER JOIN jbc2014_vragen 
ON jbc2014_lezingen.id=jbc2014_vragen.lezing_i
GROUP BY jbc2014_lezingen.id
```

and then just get the values with

```
explode(",",$row['vraags']);
```

or create another array with something like this

```
foreach($raw_result as $key => $value){
   $new_array[$key]['lezing_id'] = $value['lezing_id'];
   $new_array[$key]['vraags'] = explode(",",$value['vraags']);
}
```